# How to inject log property in Grails 3 unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-3.0

I'm trying to upgrade my Grails 2 project to Grails 3. I'm having problems with running tests for code blocks that use logging as it throws `NoSuchPropertyException` for `log` property. This was no problem with Grails 2 as the property is automatically injected. How do I get this working in Grails 3? I'm using 3.0.2.

Comment: you have a class, that has `log....` calls in it, that is annotated with `@Slf4j` and it all works in your application, but it fails when calling code from that class in your tests?

Comment: `log` is automatically injected by the framework supposedly. There's no annotation, or even declaration required in Grails 2.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `@groovy.util.logging.Slf4j` class annotation to your Spec and `log` will be injected.

Answer (score -1):

I've been doing this in my Groovy classes, I don't know whether this will work for your tests:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

// within my class that I want to call log on
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class)

// now you can call log from within a method
log.info("Log foo")
```

Comment: I think that is not exactly the answer @PsychoPunch is looking for. Every Grails artefact (controller, service, taglib, ..) gets the `log` instance injected by the Grails 2 framework. Did that change in Grails 3.0?

Comment: I found that the `log` instance wasn't injected in Grails 3 automatically, which it had been in version 2.4.3.  The workaround I cite in my answer was how I accomplished it.